# two column layout, content first

Tags: css, layout, html, multiple-columns

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>    
    <div id="content"></div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    background: blue;
    height: 900px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
    background: red
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/aFrPc/

**While this works, I would like to have `#content` listed first (instead of `#sidebar`).
Div #content must fill all remaining space.**

Image of final wanted result:
[image]

Comment: So, you're saying that you want `content` on the right, not the left?

Comment: Just change `float:left;` to `float:right;` if you want content on the right

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "listed first"?  If you mean your want `#content` on the left, you would just make `#content` `float:left` instead of `#sidebar`.  Or, maybe I'm not understanding your question (the work day is almost over and my brain is not at 100% ;) )

Comment: I mean to div #content be first in source code, after it should come div #sidebar. However on rendered layout, div #content should appear as it comes after div #sidebar :)

Comment: What browser are you using?  Your code works in the lastest version of Firefox, Chrome and IE (at least "it works on my machine"). In other words, on my computer with your code, sidebar (red) is on the left and content (blue) is on the right and takes up all remaining space.

Comment: Yes, but order of the div in source code is not the same. In my jsfiddle first goes #sidebar, then goes #content div. I want to have same appearance, but to div #content be the first one in the source code. Hope im finally clear :)

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  (Sorry) So then the answer from @Laxcrosi is correct.  Using his (her?) CSS, putting your content div first in the source code gives the result you're asking for...unless you also don't want the `position` to be `absolute`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED If he wants the content text before the sidenav text.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddnuX/)

```
    <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <div style="padding-left:200px">
        Context
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>    
</div><!--#main-->

#content {
    background: blue;
    height: 900px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    float:right;
    color:#fff;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: This not work, because #content div should be 100% of remaining space

Comment: Answer updated to account for remaining space, using a 200px left sidebar

Answer (score 2):

Try this. #Content is listed first, and takes up 100% of the remaining space after a 200px sidebar:

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#content {
  background: blue;
  height: 900px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:200px;
}

#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 900px;
  background: red
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VkQ6U/

Comment: @RhymeGuy, sorry misunderstood the question. I updated my answer.